# Spring ehCache skip caching according to a bean value

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I would like to know whether it's possible to skip caching by some external condition, e.g. a bean field value.

I have the following caching method:

```
@Cacheable(value = "MY_CACHE", keyGenerator = "myKeyGenerator")
public List<CloudEntity> getTestMetaRecords(final String someParam) {
    ...
    return aRetrievedList;
}
```

What I want is to skip caching values not related to caching method.
I know that there is the `unless` parameter inside the `@Cacheable` annotation, but I didn't manage to make it work. I added the following:

```
unless = "#myBean.getSomeValue().equals(${value.from.properties})"
```

Any help is much appreciated!

**Update:**

Ok, I've found that the `unless` and `condition` parameters can be used both for conditional caching but they use limited set of metadata in spel:
`methodName, method, target` ...
And I was able to do it only by referring the called object field via the `root.target` expression.

My result code is the following:

```
@Cacheable(value = "MY_CACHE", keyGenerator = "myKeyGenerator", condition = "#root.target.myBean.getSomeValue().equals(#root.target.valueFromProperties)")
```

What I don't like in this solution is that the target class with caching method have to be changed to include my dependency `myBean`.

Is there a more flexible solution for that?

Comment: Is it possible to evaluate a JSON which returns as a String Object using unless?  I have the following value in JSON, {"status":"FAILED","errorcode":"0001","error":"..."}. I want to check as " unless='#result.status==FAILED' ". Is it possible to evaluate this expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had more or less the same problem.

In fact, the context of SpEL expression for the `condition` or `unless` props of `@Cachable` annotation doesn't allow retrieval of the bean from the `ApplicationContext`.

However I was able to use the `T()` operator to retrieve the application context through a static method and then with that, I could retrieve my bean and invoke the method I needed for the condition.

So in my case, the final SpEL expression was this:

```
condition="T(my.utils.package.Registry).getApplicationContext().getBean('myBean').cachingCondition()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use target direct as, it works with me fine

```
@Cacheable(value = "MY_CACHE", keyGenerator = "myKeyGenerator", condition = "target.myBean.getSomeValue().equals(target.valueFromProperties)")
```

OR

```
@Cacheable(value = "MY_CACHE", keyGenerator = "myKeyGenerator", condition = "target.myBean.cachingCondition()")
```